Questions About Gravitational Waves and Uniform Circular Motion
I recently learned about gravitational waves, and a question came to mind:
Uniform circular motion is an accelerated motion, so it should lose energy. For example, electrons emit light during circular motion. However, classical mechanics doesn't seem to address this explicitly.
Does uniform circular motion lose energy due to gravitational waves? If so, does this mean that the conservation of angular momentum is violated over an extremely long period of time?

Have you checked the wikipedia entry?

Things like regular energy/momentum/angular momentum conservation sort of have to get thrown out the window talking about GR. There are some conserved energy-related quantities but the regular $E_0=E_1$ relations don't hold exactly (like, for example, in the case of gravitational radiation). Consider also: what happens to the energy that the CMBR used to have before redshifting? (Answer: the FLRW metric, which causes that redshift, breaks time translation symmetry and thus energy isn't conserved by Noether's theorem anymore.)

@controlgroup none of those issues is relevant to the case of an orbiting object emitting gravitational waves. Conservation of energy and angular momentum apply (certainly in the weak field limit where analytic formulae are presented).

Uniform circular motion would result in gravitational waves. The physics of the process means that is utterly negligible in most circumstances (e.g. the Earth orbiting the Sun), but becomes important when the moving objects are massive and the orbits are small.
A shrinking orbit has less energy and angular momentum. Conservation laws are quite happy with this because the gravitational waves carry away both energy and angular momentum.
I think this answers the question, but as an aside, classical physics does predict the emission of electromagnetic radiation from an "orbiting" electron and the consequent "spiralling in" of the electron. That it doesn't, is an argument for why classical physics doesn't apply in that scenario.

Thank you for your explanation!!

The reason why electrons would fall into the nucleus if they were classical particles is because they emit radiation by accelerating (circular motion) so they lose energy. However, if an object doesn't lose energy then it would follow the same orbit unless work is done on it.
The energy of a gravitational wave is SO MUCH LESS than the EM wave emitted by a rotating charge because gravity is incredibly weaker than EM. And we are not even sure if normal objects (hat, ball) emit gravitational waves at all. GR is a theory which describes very big objects over very long distances; there isn't a theory (yet) which describes how an atom should behave gravitationally.

This is perhaps a nitpick, but it is nonsense to say that gravity is weaker than EM, because they are not even measured in the same units (one is force per gram and the other is force per coulomb).  What you mean to say is that the gravitational force felt by a bound electron is (at least usually) incredibly weaker than the EM force felt by that same electron.

The first discovered double pulsar PSR_JSR70737-3039 is known to lose orbital energy due to the emission of gravitational waves. Its orbit has an eccentricity of 0.088, so it is close enough to circular to confirm the OP’s conjecture. Angular momentum is conserved because gravitational waves have intrinsic AM.
